# why openlayers map not working in vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3, openlayers-5

I have added ol package to my vue-cli project through

> npm install ol

but the map doesn't load. there is no error and I just find an empty div in the result source.

here is my code =>

the html part :

```
<div id="map-container"></div>
```

the js part :

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZSource from 'ol/source/XYZ';

export default {
    name: "page",
    data() {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    methods: {

        initMap: function () {
            new Map({
                target: 'map-container',
                view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
    },
    mounted: function () {
            this.initMap();
    },
}
```

**NOTE** => some where I found that I have to call init function as :

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
            initMap();
        })
```

but it made no difference.

guys, I'm running out of time so pls help me. 
thanks everybody who wanna help

Comment: no one? !!! no idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a TileLayer.  Something like this:

```
new Map({
  target: "map-container",
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: "https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```